# Oracle SQL union all in one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two query and get result in two row. How get result below union all in one row?

```
Select 'STACK' as NAME, 'Y' as DAY_1, 'Y' as DAY_2, null as DAY_3, null as DAY_4 from dual
union all
Select 'STACK' as NAME, null as DAY_1, null as DAY_2, 'Y' as DAY_3, 'Y' as DAY_4 from dual
```

Comment: What row do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH xrows AS (
        Select 'STACK' as NAME, 'Y' as DAY_1, 'Y' as DAY_2, null as DAY_3, null as DAY_4 from dual
         union all
        Select 'STACK' as NAME, null as DAY_1, null as DAY_2, 'Y' as DAY_3, 'Y' as DAY_4 from dual
     )
SELECT name
     , MIN(day_1) AS day_1
     , MIN(day_2) AS day_2
     , MIN(day_3) AS day_3
     , MIN(day_4) AS day_4
  FROM xrows
 GROUP BY name
;
```

[Full test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b30aa84c52baad7ff7b0b352446474a7)

Result:

```
NAME    DAY_1   DAY_2   DAY_3   DAY_4
STACK   Y       Y       Y       Y
```

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball says it should be:

```
select
  NAME
, max(DAY_1) as DAY_1
, max(DAY_2) as DAY_2
, max(DAY_3) as DAY_3
, max(DAY_4) as DAY_4
from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle added starting in 12.2 a [row_limiting_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) - simple add `fetch next 1 rows only` to the query if you need to return only one row.

```
Select 'STACK' as NAME, 'Y' as DAY_1, 'Y' as DAY_2, null as DAY_3, null as DAY_4 from dual
union all
Select 'STACK' as NAME, null as DAY_1, null as DAY_2, 'Y' as DAY_3, 'Y' as DAY_4 from dual
fetch next 1 rows only;
```

Note, that this is the *simplest possible solution* to return one arbitrary row. That matches you requirements a you did not mention if you prefere some order of the selection or even if you need to *aggregate* the information in one row.